# Cannot use selector to select Google's autocomplete suggestion element?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I have been fighting with Google today.
I have a fully functioning autocomplete on an input field with id "locationsearch".

What I want is to be able and grab the suggestions from Google's autocomplete but it seems that I can't even select the ".pac-container" class which Google uses to populate the suggestions.

My code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=se"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>

   function init() {

      // Make autocomplete
      var input = document.getElementById("locationsearch");
      var options = { componentRestrictions: {country: 'se'} };
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

      // Try to see if we can click on Google's suggestion list
      $(".pac-container").on("click", function(){
         alert("clicked on pac");
      });

   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

   </script>
</head>
<body><input id="locationsearch" type="text" onchange=""></input></body>
</html>
```

Any idea on why this doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google's autocomplete, but does `.pac-container` exist on page load? If not, you might want something like `$(document).on('click', '.pac-container', function() {...})`.

Comment: Yes it does. It exists all the time, it just happens that it is hidden. If I toggle() it, still nothing happens. I tried your code too and it didn't work.